# Do USB-C ports on all laptops have a guaranteed minimum of 1.5A output as required by spec?

Tags: usb, laptop, usb-storage, usb-c, usb-3.1-type-c

The question is regarding capability of USB-C ports on laptops with regards to minimum supported output power. This is negotiable either via analog resistor pull-up (answered [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282072/usb-type-c-legacy-port-current-draw/282081#282081)) or specific digital mode, so is it correct to reliably expect any reputable major manufacturer e.g. HP Dell to implement full 1.5 A capability if needed by bus-powered / host-powered devices via Type-C, or is it limited to 0.9 A on laptops.

I know there are variables like cable & external device capability, but my main question is specific and limited to host only for the moment, assuming the ideal cable and external device support full capabilities needed for 1.5 A and requires the power.

Found confusing information on wikipedia [USB_hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Power) [USB-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C) [USB 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0). USB IF probably require any USB-C port to have minimum 1.5A output at 5V. Probably that is only with [charging protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#BCS).

My doubt stems from the fact that since USB-C is a connector (on smartphones they are mostly USB 2.0) while laptop manufacturers might be supporting any of the standards - USB 3.0, USB 3.1, USB 3.2, where power output might be *only* 0.9A / 4.5W though with USB 3.2 branding. This may be especially true on budget laptops with non-PD USB-C ports.

Comment: You are likely safe with the ports, but remember that USB 3.0, USB 3.1, and USB 3.2 are all the same identical specifications.  The USB standard name the exact something, using three difference versions, faster versions exist i.e. USB 3.2 Gen 2

Comment: There are a ton of improperly made USB Type-C cables

Comment: @Ramhound I understand the cable situation. Though I'm bothered by whether manufacturers give the full current / power spec on laptops with basic USB-C ports. Basically, I want to know if it is 0.9 A vs 1.5 A for external devices that are dependent on port power supply or if the situation is "depends" on manufacturer. Also, if it is differentiable by looking at USB version supported between 3.2 gen 1 (~ 
 3.1) & 3.2 gen 2 (multi-lane).

Comment: There was a Google Android employee a number of years ago, who bought like 30 Type-C cables from Amazon and discovered that a not so insignificant amount of cables actually violated the PD specification. Best way to avoid any confusion is buy quality cables, if you need faster data transfer then buy a phone that supports it, and a laptop that has 3.2 Gen 2 or a PD specific port.

Comment: So what's the question ? It can be answered for a specific model, but not for the entire market.

Comment: The question is regarding capability of USB-C ports on laptops with regards to minimum supported power. This is negotiable either via analog resistor pull-up ([answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282072/usb-type-c-legacy-port-current-draw/282081#282081)) or specific digital mode, but my question is may I reliably expect any reputable major manufacturer e.g. HP Dell to implement full 1.5 A capability if needed by bus-powered / host-powered devices via Type-C, or is it limited to 0.9 A on laptops.

Comment: We may be able to provide answers for specific hardware, but there's no was we can provide an exhaustive list of specs for all possible hardware.

Comment: I think you are asking for opinions.  Only HP and Dell know why they made the decisions they did, if any.  It is a laptop, where one of the goals is to save power.  Some devices require split cable with power being fed from elsewhere.